# Pass data to parent view | Express.JS, Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, view

I have the following code in one of my controllers:

```
module.exports.main = function (req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('dashboard', {
      title: 'Welcome to ENIGMA VI',
        data: {
          firstLogin: req.user.firstLogin,
          name: req.user.name,
          isAdmin: req.user.isAdmin
       }
    });
  } else {
     res.redirect('/?err=' + encodeURIComponent('Please login first.'));
  }
};
```

The view `dashboard.jade` extends another parent view called `layout.jade` and I'm using the data passed to `dashboard.jade` in that view. The problem is: **it works**, however, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: C:\Users\Rafay\Dropbox\Development\Enigma\app_server\views\layout.jade:34
    32|           #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
    33|             ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
  > 34|               - if(!data.firstLogin)
    35|                 +renderApplicationMenu()
    36|               li.active
    37|                 a(href='/')

Cannot read property 'firstLogin' of undefined
```

My question is this: why can I access `data` in `layout.jade` when though it is throwing an error. Secondly, is there a better way to pass variables around in views?

Comment: What do you mean by you are able to access the data even if there is an error? Do you mean that you can see the view that you are expecting?

Comment: @Svabael I'm accessing `data.firstLogin` in `layout.jade` to set an item in the menu to appear or not based on value. I'm able to access that variable and the menu is rendered correctly, however the error is still thrown.